# How to redefine a forward-slash symbol?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm trying to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{2in}
\ttfamily
Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The text is not being hyphenated (because LaTeX [doesn't hyphenate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429569/how-to-force-latex-to-hyphenate-monospaced-font) monospace fonts) and I'm getting "Overfull \hbox". The only solution I've found is to redefine the forward-slash to "forward-slash with `\-`." How can I do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `\slash` macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two comments up front: (a) I will assume that you're not really interested in hyphenating the word "hello" *per se*, the more so as standard English-language hyphenation practice frowns on hyphenating `hello` as `hel-lo`. (ii) You mention *hyphenation* several times, but I think that what you are really looking to get is better *line-breaking*, especially by avoiding overfull lines. (What's the difference: line-breaking doesn't necessarily involve sticking hyphenation characters at the ends of lines.)

If (big if!) these assumptions are valid, I think you can proceed along two ways:

- Replace instances of `/` with `\slash`. This will allow LaTeX to insert line breaks after `\slash`. This'll avoid creating overfull lines, but it may well result in underfull lines.
- Encase the strings in question in `\seqsplit` or `\url` directives.

The horizontal line in the following screenshot is there to illustrate the width of the `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{seqsplit} % for '\seqsplit` macro
\usepackage{xurl}     % for '\path' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{2in} % just to illustrate width of minipage
\hrule
\phantom{.}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
\ttfamily
Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello
\end{minipage}\hspace{0.6in}--- bad!

\medskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
\ttfamily
Hello/\-Hello/\-Hello/\-Hello/\-Hello/\-Hello
\end{minipage}\quad--- hyphen char.\ looks odd

\medskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
\ttfamily
Hello\slash Hello\slash Hello\slash Hello\slash Hello\slash Hello
\end{minipage}\quad--- better

\medskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
\ttfamily
\seqsplit{Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello}
\end{minipage}\quad--- with \verb+\seqsplit+

\medskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in}
\ttfamily
\path{Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello/Hello}
\end{minipage}\quad--- with \verb+\path+

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\seqsplit` does the job perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's quite what you want unless you want to have output of:

```
Hello/Hello/Hello/-
Hello/Hello/Hello
```

Assuming you actually just want to allow breaks at the slashes, you could instead set the `\hyphenchar` for the font to `/`. There are two gotchas: `\hyphenchar` is global. If you set it in a group, it will still apply outside of the group and you could also inadvertently have something typeset like:

```
Something ridicu/
lously absurdly
prolix
```

The second problem is the easier one to solve and is built into LaTeX's kernel. We can use `\language\l@nohyphenation` to turn off all hyphenation.¹

The first problem is a bit trickier. What we'll do is save the current hyphen character and use `\aftergroup` to restore it when the current group ends. Putting all of this together to give us our specialized version of `\ttfamily`, we can do:

```
 \makeatletter % ❶
 \NewDocumentCommand{\mytt}{}{% ❷
    \ttfamily
    \language\l@nohyphenation
    \xdef\@restorehypenchar{% ❸
       \hyphenchar\the\font\the\hyphenchar\font
    }%
    \aftergroup\@restorehyphenchar
    \hyphenchar\font`/\relax
 }
 \makeatother
```

Note that we need access to private LaTeX commands ❶. And if you're stuck using an outdated LaTeX you can replace the line labeled ❷ with:

```
\newcommand{\mytt}{
```

We use `\xdef` at ❸ because we need to expand the contents of the definition (the resulting definition will be something akin to `\hyphenchar \OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 -1`) and it must be global since it's going to be expanded after the current group is completed.

You can then use `\mytt` in place of the `\ttfamily` in your example.

This is a little fragile. If you do something like

```
 {\mytt {\mytt foo}}
```

you won't get the original hyphenchar for typewriter type back when you exit since the inner `\mytt` will overwrite the outer `\mytt`'s definition of `\@restorehyphenchar`.

---

1. This, in fact, is how hyphenation is suppressed in verbatim mode.